# Chrome ignores range slider thumb style override

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to modify the default color of a range slider in a Webkit browser (Chrome). Below is what I have so far.

Unfortunately, despite setting the `background` to `none` and overriding the default browser styles, the thumb is still blue when rendered by the browser.

Why is this occuring and how can I fix it?

```css
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  height: 2cm;
  background: pink;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Audio settings:</p>

<div>
  <input type="range" id="volume" name="volume" min="0" max="11" />
  <label for="volume">Volume</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="range" id="cowbell" name="cowbell" min="0" max="100" value="90" step="10" />
  <label for="cowbell">Cowbell</label>
</div>
```

Comment: As a side note to this, styling the browser default input controls is notoriously difficult/unreliable. If you need control over the exact UI of a control, you would be better using a library which generates them as HTTML structures which you have full control over - although note this may be at the cost of accessibility.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan In reality I'm designing a resume which would use these sliders to indicate a persons skill level in various areas, such as programming languages or technical skills. So I don't really need it to be an input element at all. What libraries would you recommend?